# Plotting a Photocell Sensor Data in the Real-time

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, gpio

I am trying to plot a data coming from a photocell sensor in the real-time, is there anyway to do that by using matplotlib? I'm trying to find how to do that but I didn't find a way to plot my data directly from the GPIO bin without taking the data from a txt file.

Many thanks in advance

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

## Reading data from a photocell sensor

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Tell the GPIO library to use Broadcom GPIO references
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

#define the pin that goes to the circuit
Pin = 7

def RCtime (Pin):
  measurement = 0
  #Output on the pin for # Discharge capacitor
  GPIO.setup(Pin, GPIO.OUT)
  GPIO.output(Pin, GPIO.LOW)
  time.sleep(0.0001)

  GPIO.setup(Pin, GPIO.IN)
  # Count loops until voltage across capacitor reads high on GPIO

  while (GPIO.input(Pin) == GPIO.LOW):
    measurement += 1
  return measurement

# Main program loop
i = 1
while True:
    file1 = open("Data%i.txt" %i ,"w")
    i += 1 
    c = 1
    while c <= 50:
        print RCtime (Pin)*1.000
        c += 1
        file1.write(str(RCtime (Pin)))
        file1.write("\n")

    else:
      file1.close()
```

I edited the code as below, now I'm getting this error:

```
  File "/home/pi/Qt_Project/plot.py", line 43
    for RCtime (Pin) in range(0, 500):
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

The new code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import threading

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

Pin = 7

threading.Timer(2, RCtime (Pin)).start()

def RCtime (Pin):
    measurement = 0
    GPIO.setup(Pin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(Pin, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.0001)

    GPIO.setup(Pin, GPIO.IN)

    while (GPIO.input(Pin) == GPIO.LOW):
        measurement += 1
    return measurement


i = 1
while True:
    file1 = open("Data%i.txt" %i ,"w")
    i += 1 
    c = 1
    while c <= 50:
        print RCtime (Pin)*1.000
        c += 1
        file1.write(str(RCtime (Pin)))
        file1.write("\n")

    else:
        file1.close()


figure, axis = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 9))

for RCtime (Pin) in range(0, 500):
    axis.plot(time.time(), RCtime (Pin), '0-')


plt.show()
```

Comment: The short answer is yes, it is possible to plot the data with matplotlib. But as we do not know how your data `measurement` looks like, and what exactly you want to plot, we cannot help you. You may read a bit on how to plot data in matplotlib, write some code to actually do that and then edit your question, in case it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure, axis = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.6, 6.1))

for x in range(0, 500):
    axis.plot(x, x*2, 'o-')

plt.show()
```

combined with

```
import threading
threading.Timer(2, RCtime (Pin)).start() #calls func "RCtime" every 2 sec
```

Or perform a self recursion (whilst avoiding recursion depth exceeding..)

Greets Dr. Cobra

Comment: Thanks Dr. Cobra for your answer, I edited the code as shown above "after editing the question", and I successfully have got the figure, but it doesn't update, do you know why? Thanks, – M. Lagha 6 mins ago

Comment: First of all throw your while True loop out!

Comment: you have to plot your GPIO.output values in "axis.plot(time.time(), **ADD GPIO OUTPUT VALUE HERE**, 'o-')"

Comment: I edited the code as above, now I'm getting this error:



File "/home/pi/Qt_Project/plot.py", line 43
for RCtime (Pin) in range(0, 500):
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call